# Clear local notification with same category from notification panel, iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to set time duration for a local notification to be displayed in notification panel, so that all notifications will be eventually cleared from notification panel after certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You can not clear the local notifications until your app is not launched. When launched you can clear existing notifications using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
```

Where `notification` is the notification which you want to cancel. You can persist time when local notification was persisted. On next launch based on that time you can decide whether to cancel notification or not.

Comment: cancelAllLocalNotifications() doesn't seem to clear already fired notification list, as far as I know it is ment to  cancels the scheduled notifications. I need to clear all notifications which have already fired and currently visible in notification panel.